# Uploading photos in mysql and display using PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

**Hello guys, please help!**
I'm having problems with my project, I followed these steps on how to upload(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ipa9xAs_nTg) but something is wrong. 
The error is Notice:

> Undefined index: tmp_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\LDEVERACATERING\upload_process.php on line 16

Here is my upload.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min"></script>
            <script src="jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min"></script>
        <title>
        Image Upload
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="content">
                <form method="POST" action="upload_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000"/>
                    <div>
                        <input type="file" name="image"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Say something about this image..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image"/>
                    </div>
                </form>

        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

here is my upload_process.php

```
<?php
$msg = "";
//if upload button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
  //path to store the upload image
  $target = "photos/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
  //connect to database
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "catering_info");
}   
//get all the submitted date from the form
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$text = $_POST['text'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO photos_upload(image, text) VALUES('$image', '$text')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql); //stores the submitted date into the database table: images
//now let's move the upload image into the folder: photos
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name']['name'], $target)) {
  $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
}
else
{
  $msg = "There was a problem uploading image";
}
?>
```

**PLEASE HELP ME, I REALLY NEED IT. Also I'm still new to this, I just started web prog last 3 weeks :( Thank you very much!**

Comment: Read this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by replacing your code

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name']['name'], $target)
```

With these

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)
```